# R CMD Check dependency error "the condition has length > 1"

Tags: r

Recently, when running R CMD Check on my package, the following `NOTE` begun appearing when running R CMD Check:

```r
N  checking dependencies in R code (880ms)
   Error in if (pkg %notin% c(depends_suggests, common_names)) bad_exprs <<- c(bad_exprs,  : 
     the condition has length > 1
   Execution halted
```

None of my written functions uses the `%notin%` operator. Where should I go about in the codebase to look for the error? Could this be a problem with one of the packages in dependencies or `DESCRPTION`? Here is a link to the github CI output of the R CMD Check if anyone's interested: https://github.com/Qile0317/APackOfTheClones/actions/runs/5002483520/jobs/8962495554#step:5:92

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in the check code, but it is triggered by a bug in your code.  You have things like this in a couple of places:

```
suppressPackageStartupMessages(require(
  packages[[i]], character.only = T
))
```

Because you used `T` rather than `TRUE`, the bug is triggered.  `T` is a variable which might change, whereas `TRUE` is a constant.  You should always use the constant in your code.  I imagine the check code is replacing `T` with some other value and that causes all the confusion.